# Python: Prefixing Timestamps to Existing files

Tags: python, timestamp

I'm trying to make a python script that will find the Last Modified timestamp of an existing file and rename the file with that timestamp as a prefix.

For example: `myfile.txt 2018-07-22` to: `2018-07-22 - myfile.txt`

Here is the code I have so far - which falls short of solving the problem.

```
import os
import time


dirname = os.getcwd()
for item in os.listdir(dirname):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname,item)):
        timeformat = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(item)))
        print ("%s %s" % (timeformat,item))
```

Comment: Where does it fall short in solving the problem? Are there any errors that occur? You never really asked a question in your post for others to answer.

Comment: how do you rename the files like what is seen in the output? I got it to print to screen the way I wanted them to, but I can't figure out how to actually rename them.

Answer (score 1):

To rename the file there is a function called [`os.rename(src, dest)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) which will allow you to change the name of the file.

```
dirname = os.getcwd()
for item in os.listdir(dirname):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname,item)):
        timeformat = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(item)))
        new_name = '%s %s' % (timeformat, item)
        os.rename(item, new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time
import shutil


dirname = os.getcwd()
for item in os.listdir(dirname):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname,item)):
        timeformat = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(item)))
        newfile = timeformat+item
        shutil.move(item, newfile)
```